# PHP database login

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

Please help me with this, what did I do wrong? I'm trying to create a login system and connect my MySQL database: Once again, trying to connect my MySQL database with this login system.The login system will be done in Flash.Thanks guys :)

```
<?php
 $dbhost = "databasehost";
$dbname = "users";
$dbuser = "users";
$dbpass = "pass";

//Connect to database

mysql_connect ( $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass)or die("Could not connect: ".mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($dbname) or die(mysql_error());

    // The response variable
    $res = "res=KO";


    // Check incoming data
    if ($_POST['$dbuser'] != "" && $_POST['$dbpass'] != "")

    {
        foreach($allowedUsers as $dbname => $dbpass)
        {
            if ($_POST['$dbuser'] == $name && $_POST['$dbpass'] == $password)

            {
                // Ok, user found
                $res = "res=OK";
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    print $res;
?>
```

Comment: StackOverflow is not the proper place for this question. We do not do code debugging. You need to do your own debugging and if you aren't sure why something is not working as expected, post the code with an explanation of what you were expecting it to do, and what is is actually doing including all error messages. See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice).

Comment: what does the error say?

Comment: @RyanB it doesn't return an error, it just says wrong username or password when I login.. even though i know it's right.

Comment: inb4 don't use mysql* methods. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php

Comment: Just enable `display_errors` and set `error_reporting` to `E_ALL` and you'll see what's wrong... ;)

Answer (score 0):

If your MySQL instance is running on the same machine, chances are that your host is "localhost" and not "databasehost", unless you changed your hosts file. If not, then you might want to change the host to the IP where your MySQL instance is running.

Comment: My server is a web server.